# set variable to the same variable modified?

Tags: haskell

I have a program I'm trying to create of a one line text editor
I've come to a bit of a wall at this point.
I have a `list` of letters called `left` and one called `right`
perhaps in a function or a do list how can I set left to `left ++ char` where char is a user inputted char. I understand it's not possible to modify lists but can I redefine them?
If this pseudo code helps

```
left = "hello"
in = get user input
left = left ++ in
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, kinda, you can "shadow".  But it will be as if the new binding is completely separate from the old one -- you can't do anything with shadowing that you couldn't do with just using a different name for the new definition.

Comment: What would be the difference between "modify" and "redefine"? Once a variable has been bound to a value, that can no longer be changed. But you can define a new variable to some new value -- the new variable might even have the same name as the old one, but it's still a new variable.

Comment: Well, you can shadow `left` with something like `let left = "new" + "value"`, but `let left = left ++ in` will create a recursive definition of `left`; it does not create a new `left` whose value is the old value of `left` combined with `in`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [State Monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) is for. The link should help (it points to a tutorial).  Your example would then become:

```
type Line = State String ()
addInput :: String -> Line
addInput inp = do
   left <- get
   put $ left ++ inp
runState (addInput <user input>) "hello"
```

This does, however, require getting to know monads a bit.  Follow the examples in the link.

Comment: I remark that one can shorten this to `addInput inp = modify (++inp)`.